# Jquery Superslides autoplay restart on new slide

Tags: jquery, slider, reset, playback, autoplay

I am using the Superslides - fullscreen slider for jQuery.
My problem is that whenever I click the slider navigation the autoplay doesn't reset.
You can see below my settings, as you can see the **play** is set to 10000ms.
However, when I click navigation (next slide), the play timer is still running.
This means that the autoplay resets every 1000ms instead on every slide.
You can see the functions I have now:

```
 Superslides = function(el, options) {
   this.options = $.extend({
    play: 10000,
    animation_speed: 600,
    animation_easing: 'swing',
    animation: 'slide',
    inherit_width_from: window,
    inherit_height_from: window,
    pagination: true,
    hashchange: false,
    scrollable: true,
    elements: {
      preserve: '.preserve',
      nav: '.slides-navigation',
      container: '.slides-container',
      pagination: '.slides-pagination'
    }
  }, options);
```

Any ideas how can I make the "play: 10000" reset on every new slide.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently ran into the same problem and thought I would share what I think fixed it for me in case anyone else runs into it.

In the jquery.superslides.js file the following code is listed to control the navigation arrows of the slider:

```
that.$el.on('click', that.options.elements.nav + " a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  that.stop();
  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    that.animate('next', function() {
      that.start();
    });
  } else {
    that.animate('prev', function() {
      that.start();
    });
  }
});
```

So my understanding is that clicking the arrows never initiates a "stop" which means the autoplay doesn't stop so it doesn't reset. You could try two options to get around this.

Option 1 is to make the slideshow come to a complete stop when you click the next (or previous) arrow and not autoplay at all. Do this by changing

```
that.start();
```

to

```
that.stop();
```

Option 2 would be to first call for a stop and then call a start when clicking the arrows. This should force the autoplay function to reset the timer back to 10000ms you set. to do this you would just add:

```
that.stop();
```

Before each of the

```
that.start();
```